# How to match perfect number using like operator in sql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite

In my database i have a table which stores a json object as a text datatype

Example:

Table name `users`

```
id | role_ids | is_active
---+----------+----------
1  | [1, 3, 5]| t
2  | [1]      | t
```

here the column `role_ids` is json object which stored as text

I need to query the user based on the role_ids for that am using `like` operator

Example:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE role_ids LIKE '%1%';
```

in this case suppose the `role_ids` field is having 91 or any other values which is having 1 will be selected,

How can i select the rows which is perfectly having 1 just by using a single query in `SQLite`

Comment: mysql or postgresql ?

Comment: ... or is it SQLite?

Comment: @Oto Shavadze i know how to use it with postgresql that is very simple i just need to use @> thats it, But i want to know how we can implement the same thing with mysql or sqlite3

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sqlite

Comment: Be explicit in your question then!

Comment: @OtoShavadze the thing is i have implement a database for my project in postgres and i need to use the same structure database with my android application (offline purpose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be using regular expressions for that purpose, since you're looking for a specific number means that number not being followed nor lead by a numeric character :

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE role_ids REGEXP '[^0-9]1[^0-9]'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fef948/3)

Comment: I prefer this over my answer, at least in this particular case +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, I apreciate your fair behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `role_ids` columns would only ever have a single level JSON array, we can try converting that value into a pure CSV value, and then doing the `LIKE` comparison:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE
    ',' || REPLACE(SUBSTR(role_ids, 2, length(role_ids) - 1), ' ', '') || ','
        LIKE '%,1,%';
```

Here is the progression of the string operations, e.g. against `[1, 3, 5]`:

```
[1, 3, 5]
1, 3, 5     (after SUBSTR)
1,3,5       (after REPLACE)
,1,3,5,     (after ||)
```

With the roles in the format of `,1,3,5,` it is then becomes possible to easily check for any role.  As a side note, you should avoid storing unnormalized data in your database tables.

Comment: It is possible to do without converting into another format, because i saw one of the way somewhere in SO, but i forgot it

Comment: SQLite seems to offer some JSON functions, but I don't know if they would be available on Android.

Comment: `but it is not working` ... do you think that helps me to update my answer?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: To enable json functions we need to enable `JSON1 Extension`. That is natively  sqlite3.9 doesn't support json or jsonb functions. To enable json1 extension i need to build the sqlite3.9 compiling the `JSON1 Extension`. but don't know how to do that

Comment: Hmmm...Android on the Java side certainly supports rich JSON APIs.  Maybe you could do the check in your app, rather than on the database?